# Is there a special role in the word "out" in this sentence/phrase?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

In the phrase/setence:

"I can buy out of the back of a truck"

I see the word "out" as an opitional in this sentence. I think the sentence would be clearer as:

1- "I can buy  of the back of a truck"

OR

2 - "I can buy from  the back of a truck"

is the assumption of the word "Out" to be optional correct?

Comment: No. Your sentence (2) is valid; _from_ and _out of_ mean the same here. (1) is not correct.

Comment: Although you might say "**off** the back of a truck".

Comment: @Kate Bunting, would you say the use of "Of" preposition in sentence (1) is incorrect

Comment: The combination _buy of_ is not used in current English. In archaic English it referred to the goods being purchased rather than the place, as in "Buy of my wares".

Comment: The phrase options are 'buy out of' or 'buy off' or 'buy from'.

Comment: @all, I'm sorry insisting on this. Its because a learner curious mind Why "buy of" is not acceptable? I mean it's understandable the phrase (1) to a listener right?

Comment: @EulleraValiente I am not sure there is a better answer than "Because that's how English works."  The correct preposition to use in any particular sentence often seems random.

Comment: From [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buy+of+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t) you see that the incidence of **buy of** has greatly declined since the early 19th century, and in the modern examples **buy** is mostly a noun - "The Government buy of [equipment]" or "of [date]". (1) would sound very odd to a native speaker.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, very clarifying answer.